# Resultado de response.isEmpty siempre da el mismo resultado

Tags: php, java, android, login, response

Buen dia , soy nuevo en la plataforma y en esto de programar , estoy trabajando en un proyecto de eCommerce  en android pero me atore en la parte del login de user este hace una conexión a un servido local por webService(php).
puedo hacer insert por POST del registro y todo correcto pero al hacer la validación me arroja siempre el mismo resultado (true) en la comparación usando if(!response.isEmpty()) ya hice pruebas del resultado que me arroja sin el isEmpty y me manda siempre una consulta a mi base de datos , agarra el primer elemento en la tabla o si ingreso datos en el layout de android  me trae los datos de mi consulta es decir siempre me arroja  un dato por eso la sentencia siempre es verdadera pero en teoria si no concuerdan los datos del layout con la DB debe regresar un dato null o 0 es decir else .
también quite el "diferente" osea deje solo el if(response.isEmpty()) pero pasa lo contrario siempre da otro resultado parece ser que no toma los layout pero si quito el siEmpty si trae resultados (o una consulta de la primera fila o lo que le ingreso en el layout)
Saludos.

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
$user_email=$_POST['usuario'];
$id_password=$_POST['password'];

//$user_email="victor.icp@hotmail.com";
//$id_password="12345";

$sentencia=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_usuario WHERE user_email=? AND id_password=?");
$sentencia->bind_param('ss',$user_email,$id_password);
$sentencia->execute();

$resultado = $sentencia->get_result();

if ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo json_encode($fila,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);     
}

$sentencia->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

*********** ESTE EL CODIGO DE JAVA EN ANDROID ***********

```
public void VentanRegistro(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Registro.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void ValidarUsuario(String URL) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
           // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+ response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(!response.isEmpty()){
               // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Entro al login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+response.isEmpty(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), mainMenu.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "USUARIO O CONTRASEÑA INCORRECTA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> paramentros = new HashMap<String, String>();

            paramentros.put("usuario", edtUsuario.getText().toString());
            paramentros.put("password", txtPass.getText().toString());
            return paramentros;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.isEmpty()`  revisa únicamente si una cadena esta vacía, pero no revisa si el valor es `null`  por lo tanto deberías agregar también esta validación.

Revisa estos ejemplos, de como ingresaría dentro del `if`:

```
if(response != null && response.isEmpty()){
  //La respuesta es vacía.
}

if(response != null && !response.isEmpty()){
  //La respuesta NO es vacía.
}
```

por lo tanto tu código debería validar únicamente si la respuesta no es vacía entonces realiza el `Intent`, de otra forma muestra el `Toast` indicando usuario o contraseña incorrectos:

```
       if(response != null && !response.isEmpty()){
           // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Entro al login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+response.isEmpty(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), mainMenu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "USUARIO O CONTRASEÑA INCORRECTA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```